# Iterating all elements within a for loop with Python to extract JSON data

Tags: python, json, csv, export

I have the below example data in a file and I'm using Python with the below code to get data out of it to a CVS file and the logic seems to work fine with other data with less elements using the `writerow()` function.

I'm having trouble figuring out how to tell this logic to dump all rows and not just the first one i.e. `[0]` and I've read and tested with putting the `for` loop in a `range(len(int)):` array or whatever this way but I keep getting errors.

If I do not specify the `[#]` element or whatever in the `writerow[item['tags']['<field>']` then I get an error about `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str` so I just cannot figure out how to tell this thing to dump all the rows for these fields in this JSON file to a CSV file, but this is what I have and that is what I tried with the `range(len)` function but I cannot get it to work.

I'm new to Python so I don't know it that well yet but from another question on another SE community for this task I was told it'd be a good tool to use for dumping JSON data to CSV and it seems to work well until I need to iterate all elements within other levels, and so on.

I also read there may be a way to use a while loop to do this but iterating with a non-while loop using the array with the `range(len)` method makes better sense to me but I'm not doing something correct in the loop for it to work. I think I'm on the right path but hoping a Python expert can help me.

### Sample Data

```
{
  "success": true,
  "devices": [
    {
      "id": 123456,
      "name": "RemoteSite123",
      "tags": [
        {
          "id": 445533,
          "name": "testtag",
          "dataType": "Float",
          "description": "",
          "alarm": "",
          "value": 0,
          "quality": "good",
          "devId": 1
        },
        {
          "id": 112233,
          "name": "Test2PSI",
          "dataType": "Float",
          "description": "",
          "alarm": "",
          "value": 0,
          "quality": "good",
          "devId": 2
        },
        {
          "id": 90011,
          "name": "Tank2",
          "dataType": "Bool",
          "description": "",
          "alarm": "",
          "value": 0,
          "quality": "good",
          "devId": 3
        },
        {
          "id": 55110,
          "name": "Tank3",
          "dataType": "Bool",
          "description": "",
          "alarm": "",
          "value": 0,
          "quality": "good",
          "devId": 4
        },
        {
          "id": 71231,
          "name": "Line4Sensor",
          "dataType": "Bool",
          "description": "",
          "alarm": "",
          "value": 0,
          "quality": "good",
          "devId": 5
        },
        {
          "id": 74321,
          "name": "WaterFill",
          "dataType": "Bool",
          "description": "",
          "alarm": "",
          "value": 0,
          "quality": "good",
          "devId": 6
        },
        {
          "id": 70589,
          "name": "tank9PSI",
          "dataType": "Float",
          "description": "",
          "alarm": "",
          "value": 0,
          "quality": "good",
          "devId": 7
        }
      ],
      "lastSynchroDate": "2016-11-08T03:32:21Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

### My Code

```
import json
import csv

with open('C:\\folder\\test.txt',"r") as file:
    data = json.load(file)

with open('C:\\folder\\test.csv',"w",newline='') as file:
    csv_file = csv.writer(file)
    for item in data["devices"]:
        csv_file.writerow([item['tags'][0]['id'], item['tags'][0]['name'], item['tags'][0]['dataType'], item['tags'][0]['description'], item['tags'][0]['alarm'], item['tags'][0]['value'], item['tags'][0]['quality'], item['tags'][0]['devId']])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try putting one more for loop to iterate over `tags` list as well

```
with open('D:\\test.csv',"w") as file:
    csv_file = csv.writer(file)
    for item in data["devices"]:
        for tag in item['tags']:
            csv_file.writerow([tag['id'], tag['name'], tag['dataType'], tag['description'], tag['alarm'], tag['value'], tag['quality'], tag['devId']])
```

Kindly lemme know whether this is what needed